# Time complexity estimation for data set filtering algorithm

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

Good day...

I'm currently working on a filtering algorithm for very specific geometrical data sets, and I'm quite lost regarding how to estimate its time complexity. From a conceptual standpoint, I understand that the time complexity is estimated as a function of n, being n the input size of the algorithm. Let me briefly describe my algorithm:

[image]

The input data for the algorithm is an initial data set and a set of filters to be applied on that data set. So, in each step, the algorithm iterates through all elements of the data set and applies the filter to each element of the data set, then decides if such element should be erased or not from the data set, and so on...

My questions are:
(I) I feel like n should be defined as the number of elements in the data set, but then I'm leaving out an important factor: the number of filters to be applied. How can I consider the number of filters in the input data of the algorithm for the purposes of time complexity estimation?

(II) Since I can't know a priori how many elements will be erased in each filter, how could I calculate the number of operations the algorithm performs as a function of n?

(III) Each filter is an independent routine that my algorithm invokes, for the calculation of time complexity of the algorithm, should I consider as well the time complexities of each individual filter? What happens if filters are user-defined and their complexities can't be known a priori?

Thank you for any clarification or clue regarding this question...

Greetings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Answer (score 1):

I am not a specialist in time complexity, however I can try to help you.

If i understood correctly, your algorithm apply N filters to your data, possibly reducing the data each time. Each filter is applied linearly to each element of the dataset. We'll work on worst-case complexity as it is easier to compute/understand.

Let's use notations:

n: length of your dataset before filter 1 is applied. As your filters can only reduce the size of your dataset, the worst-case scenario is when no filter reduces the dataset, ie each filter is applied to n elements.

T: complexity of your algorithm

Ci: complexity of ith filter. As  I don't know what kind of data you use I can't really be more precise.

M: number of filters

So we have:

T(n, M) = n*C1 + n*C2 + ... + n*CM

Now as you don't know what is the complexity of a filter we can't go much deeper, as it can vary a lot. For example if a filter is applied on integers and is just a threshold, the complexity is O(1) but if it is to test if a number a is a prime, is it O(log(a)^6)...

But if you can estime the worst-complexity among all your filter C_worst, using big Oh notations we can have the estimation:

T(n, M) = O(M*n*C_worst)

Example on integers: if a is the max of your dataset and the worst complexity filter is linear in the integer input, we have T(n, M, a) = O(M*n*a)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response... The data set is a b-rep of a solid, therefore, filter can be applied to diff topologies i.e. faces, edges, etc. So, for example, if I wanted to identify all planar faces I would iterate through all faces in data set and apply a planarity test to each of those faces, eliminating from the data set those who are not planar. I understand I should consider worst complexity of all possible filters... But the application of a filter to a face is a constant-time operation since it applies to each individual face, does the complexity of each filter matters?

Comment: If each filter has a constant-time complexity (meaning that the computation of each filter does not depends on the size of your data, for example of the size of your face or edge) you can ingnore it in the computation of the complexity of your program. i am not realy familiar with b-rep algorithms though so I don't know if your filters have constant-time complexity or not.